# Indicators do not appear in gnome-flashback session

Tags: indicator, gnome-panel

Recently, the indicators on the Gnome panel no longer appear when using a gnome-flashback session.

It happened after I installed `indicator-applet` (`indicator-applet-complete` was already installed)

They do however appear in a normal Unity session as well as the login screen.

How would I get them back? `indicator-application-service` is setup to startup automatically, but I believe fails to when starting up the `gnome-flashback` session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that the Indicator Applet was removed from the panel. If you press Super + Alt and click on the panel, you can `Add to Panel...` the Indicator Applet, then it will return.